# Object properties editing with Spring Forms

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I'm a bit confused about how an object could be edited with Spring Forms, for instance: suppose I have an object *Person* who has a lot of attributes because I obtain it from a dao, and I only want to provide the field "street" for editing, I would have this in my *PeopleController*:

```
@RequestMapping("editPerson")
public void editPerson (Model model) {
    Person person = dao.getThatPerson ();
    model.addAttribute (person);
}
```

And in my *view file* I would have nothing but this:

```
<form:form method="post" action="" commandName="person">
    <form:input path="street" />
    <input type="submit" value="Edit!" />
</form:form>
```

So when I *post* the form, will the other attributes of the *Person* object be preserved? For instance person's name, surname, username, age, etc. Otherwise, how could this be accomplished?

Comment: Be carefull when implementing this feature because in some cases you may add hole in application's security. See http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/07/spring-mvc-advisory and http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html (especially about `setAllowedFields()`/`setDisallowedFields()` methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your model object in session, like so:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("person")
public class YourController {
...
  @ModelAttribute("person")
  public Person getPerson() {
      return new Person();
  }

  @RequestMapping("editPerson")
  public void editPerson (@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {
    person = dao.getThatPerson ();
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="postperson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public void postPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {
    // do stuff with person
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best just putting the person ID and street in the model, not the whole Person. When the user submits then just update the street by either;

1 - Providing an `updateStreet(String street, int personID)` method in your DAO.
 2 - Getting the person from the DAO, setting the street then persisting the new person.